# maximum number of items in peoplepicker

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

How many users can be able to added in multiple user column [people picker field]

Answer (score 2):

The max value of “Person or group” field is 750.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide us any Microsft Docs site reference for above values